# SQL injection drop/delete from Hibernate HQL to MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring, hibernate

In Hibenate HQL, is it possible to drop a table or database as nested part of select query?

For example,

```
select name,email,(delete from Group) from User where 1=1
```

or

```
select name,email,(drop table Group) from User where 1=1
```

or after where clause somehow:

```
select name,email from User where 1=1;drop table Group;
```

In where clause scenario I get error as below:

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateQueryException: unexpected char: ';' [ FROM com.party.Group WHERE name = ?  ORDER BY name ASC ;drop table User;]; nested exception is org.hibernate.QueryException: unexpected char: ';' [ FROM com.party.Group WHERE name = ?  ORDER BY name ASC ;drop table User;]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: unexpected char: ';' [ FROM com.verecloud.nimbus4.party.Group WHERE name = ?  ORDER BY name ASC ;drop table User;]
    ... 24 more
```

Requirement is to check for possible SQL injections in the select query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL injection requires ending one statement, in order to execute a new one:

```
select name,email,(;delete from Group;) from User where 1=1 
select name,email from User where 1=1;drop table Group;
```

If you use [bind SQL parameters](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/bind-parameters), you are protected against SQL injection.

If you generate the SQL SELECT dynamically (choosing columns at runtime), you should either use [JPA Criteria](http://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-facts-always-check-criteria-api-sql-queries/) or [jOOQ](http://vladmihalcea.com/jooq-facts-from-jpa-annotations-to-jooq-table-mappings/).

Comment: You can delete the table in between session.beginTransaction and session.getCurrentTransaction().commit. Do all the select and delete operations and then commit the session.

Comment: If you use bind parameters, there's not way a client can supply a DELETE/DROP rogue parameter to your SELECT statements. For dynamically constructed SELECT statements, you need a type-safe Query Builder, like JPA Criteria. The only deletes that proceed are the one that you intentionally issued.

Comment: huh!my code checks the Domain for property supplied in projections and hence don't allow former query.The later also don't work as I specified in question it throws the exception.